# PyTorch equivalent of tf.Data

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, pipelines

I've created a pipeline using `tf.Data` (or more accurately a mix of `Pandas` and then `tf.Data`). My specific requirement is to create sequences using the `window` command (which applies a moving window with a specified window size, step and stride) and then batch these windows in order to train time series RNN's. The network is actually implemented in `JAX`/`FLAX` so I use `as_numpy_iterator()` to cast from `Tensor` to `np.array`

I'm considering moving to PyTorch and would like to migrate my pipeline. What is the equivalent in PyTorch? I've found torch.utils.data but I don't see any mention of windowing etc.